# Best way to handle a JSON call and use it's information in all views

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a API serving a JSON with all the information needed to put into my app, and it will serve with texts and all the news needed for all the views in the app.

This information and JSON will never be big enough that i need to make multiple calls or even paginate, but the information might be changed in the future since it's an app for an event, and some minimum stuff will be added to the information like, sponsors logo, and some stuff like that.

I was wondering, what is the best way to handle this? Make an API call on the appdelegate or something, save it local and make one API call per day to "update" this local file?

Also, technically speaking, how do i handle the information for all the views?

Keep reading this local file everytime a view is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

implement a singleton class that holds your data inside proper data structure(s). you need to download the JSON in the root view controller and display an activity indicator to the user. in every view controller you can access the singleton class object asking for the data relative to you controller.

Comment: So it's best to create a Singleton with a, lets say dictionary called JSON. On the root view controller make the API call and then save it to that singleton dictionary?

Comment: I prefer to parse the JSON and save the data in a proper data structure(s). let's say we have two type of data. news should be stored in nsmutablearray of news object and events an nsmutablearray of event object. you don't need to parse the JSON every time you display the data. only once after download

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put it in the app delegate -- the app delegate should remain small and only deal with APP specific issues and to do

## generally you want to keep the Separation of Concerns (dijkstra ;))

---

I would have a singleton `MyDataManager` that exposes `dataWithCompletion:` and in that method, decide if you return the cached data (saved locally) or make an HTTP Request to update it)

Answer (score 1):

For starters you can make a shared instance (singleton) to handle your API calls with AFNetworking or what ever you prefer.

Doing this only once a day is not a bright idea if the response is very small, eg. 5000 characters is only 5kb. You can download and save the images once. So I would prefer calling your API every time the app launches in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

To handle the views from your response, you need to make sure your JSON response structure (keys) are always the same.

Example: `self.eventTitle = [response objectForKey:@"event-title"];` where "event-title" should never change, your app will crash or give a (null) value.

Comment: If you need help with anything above, I will help you personally. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton object with the json serialize method. The you can instantiate your method to serialialize a JSON that is inside your singleton object wherever you want.

You can follow this guide: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/